# Harmony/chords in right hand, melody in left hand?

Tags: piano, improvisation

I'm wondering what it's called when the melody sounds lower than the harmony. Is there a special name for it and is this a common technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, pretty common.  I've not heard any special term beyond 'melody in the bass' or 'left hand melody'.